# Efficiency between lists and methods

Tags: java, performance

I was thinking of making a Sudoku solver, I have 2 questions:

1) What would be faster?

A) Go through all the empty spots, have a list of numbers (1-9) remove them if it is in   same line, or same category, then if it is length 1, add the only one remaining. Repeat   this while needed.

B) Go through all the numbers, then check all the spots to see if they can have that number. Repeat this while needed.

2) What is the most efficient List for housing a list under 9 in length?

Thanks,

Legend

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but I created a sudoku solver (it used "groups" which could be anything, even crossed lines). It was mainly an excersise for generics & collections at the time, but it finished within .2 seconds for even the hardest 9x9 sudoku. I think it used something like A, but you'll need more rules or "guessing" if you would like it to finish on anything but the most basic sudoku.

Comment: K, the problems will be easy to do. If you would like to see what I mean, feel free to search up: Rune Sudoku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 2) Not a list but a set would make sense. In this case `BitSet`.

Case 1) There are 27 rules in a 9x9 sudoku.

Case 1A) Every spot participates in 3 rules.

Case 1B) Every number is 9 times repeated; appears in 3 rules.

Answer 1) 1A and 1B should theoretical not be different, but 1A seems to make an algorithm & data structure easier.

Comment: For the BitSet, would I need 9 elements, all true then set them false as you scan?

Also, A) will make less passes through the empty spots, but take longer per spot, but B) would take less time per spot, but more loops needed.

Comment: A recursive backtracking solving would be parametrized with { **done** =int[81]}, { **todo** }. Picking the next candidate out {todo} would be in case A the _spot_ with least count of possibilites. I think B delivers the same complexity. But maybe you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I think B works! You can use a backtracking algorithm to check the empty spot with any of the 1-9 numbers(in order). Fill the spot with first available choice(1-9) and move ahead. If at any point you are unable to insert a number into a slot then backtrack to the previous slot and try a different number.
This might be helpful :

> http://edwinchan.wordpress.com/2006/01/08/sudoku-solver-in-c-using-backtracking/